# input[type="submit"]:select CSS is not working

Tags: css, button, submit, onselect

I have a .css stylesheet that has styles for my input type buttons like the following.

```
input[type="submit"]
input[type="submit"]:hover
input[type="submit"]:focus
```

the above three works but `input[type="submit"]:select` does not work. I even tried `:selected`. Does `:visited`, `:link` etc applies for `<input type="button" />` and `<input type="submit" />`?

Please help me how to get `input[type="submit"]:select` to working

Comment: Sounds like you're getting :select as a CSS selector mixed up with a jQuery one (which is actually :selected).

Comment: What do you think `:select` might/should do?

Comment: what does you mean with selected / select?

Comment: selected is not css selector.it is jquery selector.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get an effect on button click or submit event. like you click the button the user gets a feel the button is clicked by changing the background of button. can I get it done without JQuery as I don't want any code in the html page. The only code I want is just in .css file. Does the button has a visited event like hyperlink? probably not right? Anyway I want for hte selected event. Please help

Answer (score 5):

Because `:select` is not a valid CSS pseudo-class.

Answer (score 5):

Read the [CSS2 Pseudo-Classes spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors) and the [CSS3 Pseudo-Classes spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes) and you will find:
there is no pseudo-class like what you are describing.

What is your intent? What are you trying to style, and when did you want that styling applied? Perhaps you are looking for the [`:active` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)?

> *The `:active` pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.*